# How to join these 3 tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I'm looking for the right SQL request. I'm using SQLite.

I have one principal table "cmdb":

```
name    | env  | type
-------------------------
VMV1    | Prod | Virtual
SP      | Dev  | Physical
VMO1    | Dev  | Virtual
```

I have another table "vmv":

```
name  |    dns     | host  | management
---------------------------------------
VMV1  | VMV1.local | Host1 | Man1
VMV2  | VMV2.local | Host1 | Man1
```

And a another table "vmo" :

```
name |    dns      | host  | management
---------------------------------------
VMO1  | VMO1.local | Host2 | Man2
VMO2  | VMO2.local | Host2 | Man2
```

Here is what I would like to get:

```
 name  | management |    dns     | env  | type
-------------------------------------------------
 VMV1  |    Man1    | VMV1.local | Prod | Virtual
 VMV2  |    Man1    | VMV2.local |      | 
 SP    |            |            | Dev  | Physical
 VMO1  |    Man2    | VMO1.local | Dev  | Virtual
 VMO2  |    Man2    | VMO2.local |      |
```

but I cannot manage to get the right result...

Here is what got me the closest to the result. You can see that I'm not really good at all in making SQL requests more complex than "select * from table1"... I tried a lot of combinations and studied lots of examples on stackoverflow and others websites about UNION, JOIN and other SQL keywords but I unfortunetly still don't get it. That's why I'm looking now for help here.

```
SELECT
c.name, 
v.management, 
v.dns,  
c.env,
c.type 
FROM cmdb AS c
LEFT JOIN vmv AS v ON v.name = c.name
LEFT JOIN vmo AS o ON o.name = c.name
```

My result is:

```
 name | management  |    dns     | env  | type
-----------------------------------------------
 VMV1 |    Man1     | VMV1.local | Prod | Virtual
 SP   |             |            | Dev  | Physical
 VMO1 |             | VMO1.local | Dev  | Virtual
```

Comment: Why do you expect a row like: `VMV2  |    Man1    | VMV2.local | Prod | Virtual` or `VMO2  |    Man2    | VMO2.local | Dev  | Virtual` in the results? The names  `VMV2` and ``VMO2` do not exist in cmdb.

Comment: @forpas, Good question thanks! Because cmdb is not always reliable and complete. Sometimes, vmv and vmo give me servers informations that are not yet registered into cmdb.

Comment: Then there isn't any logical relation between the tables. Any name could be related to any other name so SP could also be joined to any row of the other 2 tables but its row in the results contains nulls for management and dns.

Comment: I have to admit I didn't get everything you explained. You mean that what I want to acheive is not possible right? I have to have at least a logical relation between all 3 tables ? And what do you mean by "its row in the results contains nulls for management and dns"? It is not a problem for me that these value are null in the result.

Comment: I did not say it is not possible because it is not clear what yo want to do. So how is it possible to have in the results in the same row `VMV2` and `Prod | Virtual`?  `Prod | Virtual` can be found only in the table cmdb for the name `VMV1`. So you are relating unrelated names. Is there any logic behind this?

Comment: @forpas, you are so right! I made a mistake. I correct that right away! Sorry for that. Is it better now?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join with `LEFT` joins all the distinct names of the 3 tables with each of the tables:

```
select t.name,
       coalesce(v.management, o.management) management,
       coalesce(v.dns, o.dns) dns,
       c.env,
       c.type
from (
  select name from cmdb union
  select name from vmv union
  select name from vmo
) t
left join cmdb c on c.name = t.name
left join vmv v on v.name = t.name
left join vmo o on o.name = t.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dif2GTbmH6WWrLzkL8BwWo/1).

Or:

```
select t.name,
       n.management,
       n.dns,
       c.env,
       c.type
from (
  select name from cmdb union
  select name from vmv union
  select name from vmo
) t
left join cmdb c on c.name = t.name
left join (
  select name, dns, management from vmv
  union all
  select name, dns, management from vmo
) n on n.name = t.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dif2GTbmH6WWrLzkL8BwWo/2).

Results:

```
| name | management | dns        | env  | type     |
| ---- | ---------- | ---------- | ---- | -------- |
| SP   |            |            | Dev  | Physical |
| VMO1 | Man2       | VMO1.local | Dev  | Virtual  |
| VMO2 | Man2       | VMO2.local |      |          |
| VMV1 | Man1       | VMV1.local | Prod | Virtual  |
| VMV2 | Man1       | VMV2.local |      |          |
```

Comment: exactly what I needed thanks so much, I would have not get there alone. I didn't know "coalesce" keyword. Also, "t" is it what we can call a view in SQL?

Comment: `t` is the alias for the subquery.

Comment: Hi @forpas, just a little complement question, if the name in the cmdb table is UPPER case, and the name in VMV table is LOWER case, I get two different results. I tried to play with COLLATE NOCASE in my SQL request but still no luck. Would you have any idea of what I could do to get one line and not two different lines please ?

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dif2GTbmH6WWrLzkL8BwWo/3

Comment: Perfect thanks! It's what I did for the COLLATE NOCASE but not the "upper(name)"

Answer (score 1):

In principle it looks like you want to do a `UNION` of `vmo` and `vmv`, then do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` of that result with `cmdb`.  I am not familiar with sqlite so I don't know if the exact syntax might be different from what I would write for Oracle (or if it even supports these operations).

Here's what I would try:

```
SELECT NVL(cmdb.name, vm_all.name), management, dns, env, type
 FROM
  cmdb
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT name, management, dns FROM vmv
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, management, dns FROM vmo
  ) vm_all
  ON vm_all.name = cmdb.name
```

Comment: SQLite does not support FULL OUTER join.